# Learn python the hard way exercise 17 help, mistake in the book?

Tags: python

I'm liking this book so far, but I run into an issue with exercise 17. It won't run:

```
neil@neil-K52F:~/python$ python ex17.py ex17from.txt ex17to.txt
  File "ex17.py", line 8
    indata input.read()
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The book makes me create a variable named `input`. Is this a legal variable name?

Comment: Yes 'input' is a legal variable name in python, can you post your code?

Comment: `input` is the name of a builtin function. If you create a variable with that name, you'll lose the definition as a function; if you then try to use it as the function, it won't work. Please post the code so we can see the context.

Comment: However, that doesn't cause any error at compiletime (i.e. no syntax error but a type error when trying to call it). Also, not too much of a loss as Python 2.x `input` should be avoided (as it's the worst kind of `eval`).

Comment: Yeah, I was guessing wrong at what the problem was. He's missing the `=`, that's all. However, shadowing builtin names is bad practice and should be discouraged.

Comment: Where has the code gone?

Comment: Ah, this _is_ the code: `indata input.read()`. Looked over it as it misses the assignment operator :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that book is a joke. If I remember it correctly it's basically full of timewaster exercises?

Answer (score 6):

The code you posted simply puts one identifier next to another, without anything (but a space) in between. That's as meaningless and invalid in Python as it is in English. The code in the book has an assignment in there (i.e. `indata = ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you set a value for your input/raw_input(python 2.x)

```
x = input("Text Here")
```

You may also call a data type function on input method

```
x = float(input("Enter a Number")
x = int(input("Enter an Integer")
```

I use these all the time in Python 2.7 where `raw_input()` stores the value as a string.